# Perform a comparison in Ruby without using eval

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, eval

`["if", "2", "<", "4"]`

How can I string these together and calculate whether or not they're true without using `.eval()`?

For clarification, the above is simply an array, and I need to manipulate the contents so as to evaluate `if 2 < 4`, which should return `true`.

Comment: `["if", "2", "<", "4"]` this is even not a valid Ruby code. You should specify more clearly what you need and what data you have as an input

Comment: @fl00r I know it's not valid as is. I've got an array with four strings and I want to convert them so I can evaluate `if 2 < 4`, returning `true`.

Comment: Not sure about the if, but you can do `2.send('<',4)` and get `true`. Wrap those up in variables and you're part way there. Although how you distinguish between `"2"` and `2` I don't know. `'19'.send('<', '2')` is also `true`.

Comment: What other inputs do you have?

Comment: @fl00r First element can be if/elsif/unless; second must be a string, third can be ==/</>, fourth must be a string.

Comment: Second and fourth are numbers as strings, or real strings?

Comment: If 2 is a number, it'll look like "2". If it's intended as a string, it'll look like "'2'" (notice the nested quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for parsing your statements and composing them into something more complex.

```
def bool_parse(statement)
  op, left, method, right = statement
  left = left.to_i unless left["\'"]
  right = right.to_i unless right["\'"]

  case op
  when "if", "elsif"
    left.send(method, right)
  when "unless"
    !left.send(method, right)
  end
end

def compose(statements)
  correct = statements.detect do |s, v|
    bool_parse(s)
  end
  correct && correct.last
end

compose({["if", "3", ">", "5"] => 1})
#=> nil
compose({["if", "3", ">", "5"] => 1, ["elsif", "2", ">", "-1"] => 2})
#=> 2
```

Comment: Just checking - if you're referring to 'operator' by `op`, surely that should be the ==/</> operators, not the if/elsif?

Comment: it is `operation` (as far as it comes first in your array), operator in a `method` in my notation